# React-native currency input

Tags: javascript, mobile, react-native

I'm trying to create a currency input, that starts as something like

```
" $00.00"
```

and then when you start typing, it types the cents first, then moves on to the dollars (ie, updates the right side numbers first), e.g

```
" $00.50"
```

So far I have it implemented, where the user types in one box, and the correctly formatted output displays in a second box.

Code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
        amount: '',
    };

}

formatValue(value) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(parseFloat(value) / 100, "$ ");
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>

            <Text style={styles.text}> Enter the Amount to be payed</Text>
                <TextInput
                    onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}>
                </TextInput>

                <TextInput
                    onChangeText = {amount => this.setState({amount})}                  
                    value={this.formatValue(this.state.amount)}>                        
                </TextInput>

        </ScrollView>

    );

}
```

However, I want the currency formatting to apply to the same box the user is typing into. I have tried something like this:

```
<TextInput 
        onChangeText={(amount) => this.setState({amount})}
        value = {this.formatValue(this.state.amount)}>
</TextInput>
```

but this simply sets the input to zero, and it cannot be changed. I am clearly not understanding this correctly.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do this exact thing in a recent project and I ended up releasing it as an npm package.

https://github.com/wwdrew/react-native-numeric-textinput

It uses the Intl NumberFormat for formatting currencies and numbers, so should work for any currency you want to throw at it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this package can help you out. It lets you store change value in state.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-input

Or since you only want to mask the input and not do any mutation/converting to the input you can of course do something like this;

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-input-mask

Comment: I think that the package you gave only works for react web not in native. There is other option here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-masked-input this one is for react-native